# jQuery: Can not get the content of a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have a div, which contains text loaded from a file with AJAX. When the page loaded, and the content loaded too, I want to alert the divs content. I doesn't work.

```js
var cnt = $('#htmlmsg2').get(); 
var page = $('#htmlmsg').text();
alert(+cnt+'\n'+page);
```

I have another div which has a dynamic content too, but its not loaded from a file. This part of the alert works perfectly.

I tried the .get,.html,.text (!) functions with no effect.

I tried to load the text to an other div too, and try to reach that, I failed:
I can not reach the loaded content later from any div. It gives me always 'NaN'.

Any ideas?

The body looks like this:

```
<div id="htmlmsg"></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="bodycontainer"><div id="htmlmsg2">loaded text from ajax, wich can not be reached somehow</div>
</div>
```

```
$.ajax({
  url: "pages/start.php",
  contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
    
  $("#webtext").append(html);
  $("#htmlmsg2").html(html);
});
```

This is how I load the content. (This works well!)

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: What do you mean with 'fail'? give us a jsfiddle please

Comment: My crystal ball tells me the word asynchronous will appear in the right answer !

Comment: I think we need more of your javascript to understand what's going wrong. Specifically the code use to load your text in using ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the AJAX $.get() works differently:

```js
$.get(
    url: 'mypage.html',
    params: { key1: 'hello', key2: 'world' },
    success: (data) {
        $('#mydiv').html(data);
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

If you want to just load the page:

```rb
$('#mydiv').load('mypage.html', function() {
    alert('It works!');
});

$('#mydiv').load('mypage.html');
```

**UPDATE:**

It's probably not getting the divs' content because the AJAX happens after the DOM is loaded, so you need to add your code inside the `success` block.

Comment: It's already loaded with ajax. I want to reach it later. (no load it again)

Comment: @user1628372 `var data = $('#mydiv').html()` Getting the html from `#mydiv` later

Comment: Then it might be related to the "after DOM" issue, as I stated in my update. This is why there are the `live()` and the `on()` methods (when the user wants to click some button after some AJAX happens).

Comment: @Scott the problem is that, that is does not! It returns 'NaN'.

Comment: @Vitor Ussui: The ajax loads with the page, and I want to reach it later with a button.

Comment: @user1628372 Could you please update your question with your jQuery code? Anyways, I think you need something like `$('#mybutton').on('click', function() { alert($('#mydiv').text()); });`.